# Adding ... when text is too long in a div with only CSS

Tags: html, css, tags

I would like to create a tag system . When a text in a div (a tag) is too long, I would truncate it and add "..." in the end. Is there any CSS solution in order to do it?

Comment: Search for "css ellipsis".

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `text-overflow: ellipsis` for that. Further information is in the comments of the code.

```css
div {
  width: 10em; /* the element needs a fixed width (in px, em, %, etc) */
  overflow: hidden; /* make sure it hides the content that overflows */
  white-space: nowrap; /* don't break the line */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* give the beautiful '...' effect */
}
```

```html
<div>This is a text that is too long for this div.</div>
```

Comment: is there any way to show full text on hover/tooltip or something alike?

Answer (score 7):

Here is your required css.

```css
.tag{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here

**Width** can be changed to required size.

**white-space** will make sure the text is on same line.

**overflow:hidden** will hide excess content allow text-overflow to add dots.

**text-overflow: ellipsis** will add dots

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<div class='truncate'></div>



.truncate {
     width: 250px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```